# Error with shared variables

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, shared

So, I'm struggling with shared variables in Java (NetBeans). I have one class with a variable - lets call it `statlbl`. So it's a non-editable label, and the contents thereof is changed by another class.

Here's the sitch... I have absolutely NO idea how to change the label located in the one class, with the other class.

Here's an extraction of the code:

```
//Print the ip address   
System.out.println("This server's IP Address: " + ipAddress); TS_Entity.statlbl.setText("This server's IP Address: "
    + ipAddress);
         try {
             Thread.sleep(1000L);
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }
```

When debugging, the IDE displays an error with description, "Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you declared the variable in your class as `public` and `static` ? e.g. `public static TextView statlbl;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not an object of class TS_Entity. You need to create an instance of it:

```
TS_Entity tsEntity = new TS_Entity();
```

to access non-static fields. Static fields are fields from the class, not a single instance. For every other fields, you'll need an instance of the object, like `tsEntity`, in the example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've followed your method, and it removed the error at least. The next problem is that the label isn't changed, as programmed. The init value is "READY..."

The program starts a class, which has to change the label's value to certain text in the original class from which the second class is started.

Comment: The label (variable) is set in the netbeans custom code as Public Static

Comment: You need a reference for the label you are showing. Like in my example, you are creating a new instance of TS_Entity and changes in this object won't affect others of the same class (except in a static context).

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your variable `statlbl` is not static. You either need to have an object of type `TS_Entity`, say `entity`. Your command would then be

```
entity.statlbl.setText("This server's IP Address: " + ipAddress);
```

Either that, or make `statlbl` a static variable.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `statlbl`  which you are using is a non- static variable . But you are trying to access this non-static variable `statlbl` from a method which itself is static .

This is not possible in java. You have to declare `statlbl` variable as static.

To access non-static fields from static method, you need to create Object instance like this :

`TS_Entity en = new TS_Entity()`;

now you can change value of `statlbl` by using setter method of this object .